# Differences between Multiple Integrals and Partial integrals

Tags: calculus

Both multiple integrals and partial integrals involve multiple dependent and independent variables in a single function What are major differences between multiple integrals, and partial integrals ? Do more such forms exist?

Comment: When you say "partial integration", what do you mean, exactly? Could you give an example of each of the two things you mention, so that we all know that we are talking about the same thing?

Comment: what is a partial integral?

Comment: Integration may be a reverse process of differentiation, under this way please refer https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative?wprov=sfla1

Comment: Trying to solve partial integrals the variables are independent of each other so when performing integration we treat them as constants and solve the integral w.r.t. {x1,x3,x3...} taking one variable at a time. While in multiple integral say w.r.t. variables {x,y,z...} there is relationship between x and y , x and z , y and z .... So replacing values is required..